# Samsung galaxy 3 says charging paused. Battery temperature too low

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, charging

I plugged in my S3 when it said 1% battery life and the red charging indicator light never came on, when i checked it a few minutes later it was at 0% and powered off. Immediately after that I tried to power it up and the power button did not work.  The next day it powered up but always says Charging paused battery temp too low and will not charge. I took it to a Sprint Service Center and the lady put a new battery in it and same thing. She said I need a new phone. It is only 5 months old and i dont see how this cant be fixed!

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Take out the battery and see if it's size is expanded. If yes, then the battery is pretty much dead. Just buy a new one and make sure it's genuine battery from the manufacturer, not cheap knockoffs. Else, it's a problem with the USB cable charger. A batch of S3 chargers were made in China for Samsung and they were absolutely rubbish. You might be one of the unlucky ones who got this crappy USB cable.

Answer (score 1):

Get yourself a heating pad, set it to low and slowly increment the temperature until it begins charging again. If this works, your easiest fix is to buy a battery charger and interchange batteries.

If your battery is dead, below operational then get it recharged for free at a battery store near you.

If you want to resolve the problem, then inspect the charging ports for corrosion or damage. If you have a soldering kit you may want to replace this part, if damaged, at your nearest radio shack or electrical parts store.

If the problem goes beyond that then call Samsung tech support higher levels and pick there brain of what parts on the motherboard controls the battery temperature and if they can give you a replacement part number you can order. This may be a lengthily process but would help others with this same problem.

Always recycle, your trash is another person's investment.

Answer (score 0):

As a first look I'd say that you're experiencing the sudden death symptom, but it's hard to know for certain. Try to clean your battery connectors or try with a new battery.

Answer (score -1):

It's the charging port connector. It has a thermometer sensor for the battery. It is probably malfunctioning. Replace it and see if it works out.

Answer (score -1):

I let its battery go empty for a night, then I charged it fully then switched on, and now it is working correctly again